# Scheduling jobs as file trigger in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Using oozie we could submit jobs in hadoop, is that possible to make the job submission triggered by availability of file. For an example after coping the file successfully to hdfs, Oozie has to submit the jobs. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The 'done-flag' tag in dataset. like

```
<datasets>
    <dataset name="dataset1" frequency="${coord:hours(1)}"
             initial-instance="${startTime}" timezone="UTC">
      <uri-template>
        ${dataRoot}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/
      </uri-template>
      <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
    </dataset>

</datasets>
```

If the done flag is set to empty, then Coordinator looks for the existence of the directory itself.
IF the _SUCCESS(or any file name which is specified in the tag) file is exists in your directory then coordinator will proceed further.

for more information see the - https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html